# What prevents Windows from entering standby?

Tags: windows, standby

Is there a tool or method to find out, what prevents Windows Vista 32 bit from entering the standby mode? My home pc is set to standby after a certain time of inactivity. But quite often it just stays awake and I have know idea why.
I know of things that will keep it awake and already checked devices and network to no avail. I suspect there is some application or service that tells the os to stay active and I hope there is some tool to find the culprit.

Comment: Any 3rd party driver or program running in the background can cause this. I use msconfig to start disabling startup programs and restart the PC to see if it sleeps now.

Comment: Also check your devices in the device manager, right click=> properties =>power management=> "allow this device to wake up the computer". In my case, disabling that for a USB mouse fixed this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Right click CMD and run as Administrator. Enter **powercfg -requests**

If you are lucky, it may indicate a driver preventing sleep.

Comment: thanks, great! I also found pwrtest.exe from the Windows Driver Development Kit, but powercfg does not need to be installed.

Comment: In my case, I had external audio amplifiers plugged into two different computers. `powercfg -requests` indicated the audio driver was preventing the computer from entering sleep. I used `powercfg -REQUESTSOVERRIDE DRIVER "driver name" SYSTEM` to override this. See http://www.jasonhartman.net/2012/06/windows-7-wont-go-to-sleep-mode-audio.html, which is very helpful